# How to read/format *.txt files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where I work there is a program, that will print overdue tool reports to a `.txt` document, I basically wanted to create a rails app to make my life easier, that would parse the data into a form on upload, and email to the correct people that are in the file. Is there a good read on how to do this in Rails, or can somebody give me a quick rundown? I have not seen anything for what I've tried googling (How to upload and format data from a .txt file in Ruby on Rails).

Thanks.

Edit: Not so much how to upload it, but just how to read and format it in the way I need.

Edit: Data in txt file looks like

supervisorname/id
the under that lists all employees showing their current over due tools e.g

foobar bazquux hammer

Comment: You already know how to format txt file in ruby. Rails doesn't change that. Now you just need a regular rails intro.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I actually have no idea how to format a txt file, but I'm sure I can google just fine how to upload one.

Comment: @ah, sorry, I misread. I thought you already have a working program that formats files.

Comment: Well, the answer may vary depending on format of that text file. Can you show us a short example of what have to be parsed?

Comment: @NIA11 check original post